# Install multiple versions of chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

How do I install multiple versions of Chrome? I would like to say, I want Chrome, **not** Chromium. Or is there a extension (like Firefox)?

Comment: Multiple versions or multiple profiles?

Comment: Either, as long as they are different versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want a completely separate Google Chrome installed on your machine, including files, document folders, settings, etc. you can check out Containers.

Container is a Virtual-Machine like system that isolates a process (or a set of processes) from the main system.

A set of Docker Container files for Chrome has been developed [here](https://github.com/jlund/docker-chrome-pulseaudio) to 
help you get started.

NOTE: This method may not be the easiest, and maybe there's a way easier way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: glad I helped **:)**

Answer (score 8):

**Update January 2020:**  I am splitting this answer into 3 parts.

### Part 1 (Dec 2016): Running *multiple configurations* of the *same version* of Chromium.

I launch four distinct copies of Chromium using the `--user-data-dir` as follows:

```
chromium-browser  --user-data-dir=/home/<user>/.config/chromium1
chromium-browser  --user-data-dir=/home/<user>/.config/chromium2
chromium-browser  --user-data-dir=/home/<user>/.config/chromium3
chromium-browser  --user-data-dir=/home/<user>/.config/chromium4
```

It appears the same command line option works for Chrome:
http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html

All four copies of Chromium are running the same version of the software, but they have entirely distinct configurations, cookies, caches, etc.

### Part 2 (Jan 2020): Manually installing *multiple versions* of Chromium *from Snap*.

Starting with Ubuntu 19.10, Ubuntu now distributes Chromium as a snap package.  Ubuntu no longer provides Chromium via `.deb` packages. 
 Consequently, part 3 of this answer is now obsolete.  So... below are instructions for manually downloading, manually installing, and manually running Chromium from snap packages.

**Warning:**  The below instructions use snap packages in a way that Ubuntu/Canonical most certainly neither intends nor supports.  It is possible that installing Chromium via this method may reduce or compromise Chromium's security.  And/or this method may cause other problems.  Proceed at your own risk!!

**Step 1** - Install prerequisites

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl jq squashfs-tools
```

**Step 2** - Manually find and download a snap package of Chromium

Download a JSON list of the currently active Chromium packages:

```
$ curl -H 'Snap-Device-Series: 16' http://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/info/chromium >> chromium.info
```

View the JSON list to find the URL of the package you want.  Note: The JSON list will contain multiple architectures, multiple "risk" levels, and multiple tracks, so be sure to find the right URL.

```
$ jq . chromium.info | less
```

Download the snap package of your choice.

```
$ wget 'https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/download/XKEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R_NNN.snap'
```

Note: Your URL will probably look like the above, but with a specific number rather than `NNN`.

**Step 3** - Manually extract the snap package

```
$ unsquashfs KEcBqPM06H1Z7zGOdG5fbICuf8NWK5R_NNN.snap
```

As of Jan 2020, Chromium uses 149MB of disk space.

**Step 4** - Manually run the extracted copy of Chromium

The extracted package will contain both the chromium browser executable and the libraries it uses.  In order for the browser to find its libraries, you will need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.  If you wish to simultaneously run multiple versions of Chromium, you will need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately prior to running each different version of Chromium.  Each version will need to find its libraries, and only its libraries.

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<full_path_to>/squashfs-root/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Note:  If your architecture is not `x86_64`, then you will need change `x86_64` in the above.

Then run chromium:

```
$ <full_path_to>/squalshfs-root/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome
```

Final thoughts:  You may extract the `.snap` file wherever you like.  You may rename the `squashfs-root` directory as you like.

### Part 3 (Dec 2016): Manually installing *multiple versions* of Chromium *from .deb* packages

Regarding installing different *versions* of Chrome/Chromium, this appears to be trickier, but perhaps not too tricky.  Chromium is launched via `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`, which is a shell script.  If you look at this script, you see an variable named `LIBDIR`.  Almost all of the Chromium files are installed inside this directory, so I am hoping that I can manually extract Chromium `.deb` files to non-standard locations, and then just tweak this one variable.  (Use `dpkg` to do the extraction.)  Hopefully then I can have different *versions* installed and running simultaneously.  The `chromium-browser` shell script even seems to anticipate such a configuration:

```
LIBDIR=/usr/lib/chromium-browser
# [snip]
readonly UPSTREAM_VERSION="<version>"
if test -x "${LIBDIR}/${UPSTREAM_VERSION}"/chromium-browser; then
        LIBDIR="${LIBDIR}/${UPSTREAM_VERSION}"
fi
readonly LIBDIR
```

Update:  After attempting the above, multiple versions of Chromium seem to be working.  I have two sets (different versions) of the following packages installed:

```
chromium-browser
chromium-browser-l10n
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

The first set is installed by `apt-get install`.  The section set is installed manually via `dpkg -x` in a nonstandard location.

After changing the `LIBDIR` variable in the non-standard `chromium-browser` script to the appropriate non-standard path, both versions seem to be able to run simultaneously.  I am, of course, using a different `--user-data-dir` for each version.

Comment: Good idea with `dpkg --x`, thanx!

Answer (score 1):

You can set up multiple users, each with their own profile. And then you can right-click on the current user's name near the top right-corner of your Chrome window to change users (not shown in the image below).

[image: chrome://settings]

Comment: More info please...

Answer (score 0):

Install Google Chrome Beta release - it can run alongside Google Chrome stable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the `deb` package.
2. Unpack it (`ar xo /path/to/file.deb`)
3. Unpack the `data.tar.xz` (`tar -xvf ...`)
4. Run `opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`

(obviously this bypasses dependency resolution that dpkg, which normally handles deb packages, does. However chances are high, that whatever you have installed for your existing version of Chrome will satisfy the second one too. If not - you can check them in the file `control` from `control.tar.gz` that resides in the same deb)

Comment: The question was about multiple versions of Chrome. If I follow your steps, I only get one version of Chrome.